# Terminate program if wrong data type is entered

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get this code to terminate automatically if the user enters a non-integer. As of now it recognizes a non-integer but it won't exit the program automatically.

```
double readCoeffs() {

    double i;
    bool valid = false;
    while (!valid)   {

        valid = true;
        cout << "Enter a coefficient\n" << endl;
        cin >> i;

        while (cin.fail()){  {
                //stream is the correct type, if not it returns true,
                //false otherwise.

                cin.clear(); //This corrects the stream.
                cin.ignore(); //This skips the left over stream data.
                cout << "Please enter an Integer only." << endl;
                valid = false; //The cin was not an integer so try again.
                //break;
            }
            cout << "\n";
            return i;
        }
    }
}
```

I thought a break statement would do it but I must be misunderstanding something about it...

Curious what I'm doing wrong here?? Thanks!

Comment: Throw an exception if the error is unrecoverable. In your case, it sounds like you should just prompt the user for another input.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but one thing to note is you are taking in input for a double, but your error message (and comments) say integer. Also, you have two left curly braces at the start of your while loop, which, while not necessarily wrong, it isn't particularly clear why you would want to do that in this case.

Comment: `while (cin.fail()){{` <== *two* `{` ? There meaning there, I just can't understand what it would be.

Comment: Why is `return i;` *inside* `while(cin.fail())` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you possibly think that adding a `break` or returning from a method would exit the program? This way only works if you return from `main()`.

Your best option is adding control code to whatever calls `readCoeffs()` to ensure the code exits.

Other options

- Call `exit()`
- Throw an uncaught exception

Whatever you do, don't just fail silently on bad input...